# How do I scrape some text from <span> with no unique class identifier?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to scraping so please be patient with me. I have this HTML code and I want to extract the type of property e.g. ‘Apartment’, the no. of beds e.g. 2 and the location e.g. ‘Birmingham’ only. I want to save each of these in a list. The problem is that there’s no unique class identifier.

```
<div class="extra">
    <span class="tablet-visible">
    <span class="item"><label><i class="ouricon classified"></i><b></b></label>
        <span>For Sale</span></span>
    </span>
    <span class="tablet-visible">
        <span class="item"><label><i class="ouricon house"></i><b></b></label>
            <span>Apartment</span></span>
        </span>
        <span class="">
            <span class="item"><label><i class="ouricon bed"></i><b></b></label>
                <span>2</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="">
            <span class="item"><label><i class="ouricon locationpin"></i><b></b></label>
                <span>Birmingham</span>
            </span>
        </span> 
</div>
```

I tried this code but of course this prints all the text in class=extra including the 'For Sale' which is not what I want.

```
results = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
desc_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"data-itemid": True})
for property in desc_div:
    extra = property.find('div', class_='extra')
    print(extra.text.strip())
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add website URL as well to investigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `For Sale` is in the same tag and class, just filter it out.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="extra">
    <span class="tablet-visible">
    <span class="item"><label><i class="ouricon classified"></i><b></b></label>
        <span>For Sale</span></span>
    </span>
    <span class="tablet-visible">
        <span class="item"><label><i class="ouricon house"></i><b></b></label>
            <span>Apartment</span></span>
        </span>
        <span class="">
            <span class="item"><label><i class="ouricon bed"></i><b></b></label>
                <span>2</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="">
            <span class="item"><label><i class="ouricon locationpin"></i><b></b></label>
                <span>Birmingham</span>
            </span>
        </span> 
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find_all("span", {"class": "item"})
print([i.text.strip() for i in soup if i.text.strip() != "For Sale"])
```

Output:

```
['Apartment', '2', 'Birmingham']
```